# Counters in Chained MapReduce jobs

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, iteration, chaining

I am using chained jobs. Say:

```
Job 1 -> Job 2 -> Job 3 -> Job 4 -> Job 5
```

I have created few Counters like

```
public static enum MoreEnum {
        counterA,
        counterB;
    }
```

I am using `counterA` in `Job 2` and getting correct output in Mapper and Driver. 
Even before start of `Job 5` I am able to fetch the value of `counterA` correctly.
I am using this in the driver:

> value=
>   job2.getCounters().findCounter(MoreEnum. counterA).getValue();

However, in Mapper of `Job 5`, when I do:
`Long value=context.getCounter(MoreEnum.counterA).getValue()`;
The value I am getting is `0`. Why it is so and how to fix this.

Comment: Well that counter doesnt exist in the context of job 5. In your driver you should could get the count from Job 2 and set it as a configuration variable in job 5.

Comment: Thats what I have done as a temporary workaround. So, counters get added to the job when you use them in Mappers/Reducers?